# Correct way to insert date into database depending on selected drop down

Tags: c#

I have this combobox:

[image]

Then I have this Model (All other values have been removed, just focusing specifically on `BestBeforeDtae`):

```
public class ComplaintModel
{
    public int IsBestBefore { get; set; } ----- This is the Target
    public DateTime BestBeforeDate { get; set; } // ----- And also this

}
```

Next, I am using `FluentValidation`:

```
public class ComplaintsValidator : AbstractValidator<ComplaintModel>
{
    public ComplaintsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.IsBestBefore).Must(DropDownSelected).WithMessage("Does this product have a Best Before Date?");

    protected bool DropDownSelected(int item)
    {
        if (item == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally this is how I validate it:

```
    BindingList<string> errors = new BindingList<string>();

    private void FormValidation()
    {
        errors.Clear();

        ComplaintModel complaint = new ComplaintModel();
        complaint.IsBestBefore = bestBeforeQuestion.SelectedIndex;
        complaint.BestBeforeDate = best_before.Value;

        ComplaintsValidator validator = new ComplaintsValidator();

        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(complaint);

        if (results.IsValid == false)
        {
            foreach (ValidationFailure failure in results.Errors)
            {
                errors.Add($"- {failure.ErrorMessage}");
            }

            string message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors);
            MessageBox.Show(message, "Empty Fields", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            insertComplaintForm(); // Database insertion
        }
    }
```

**So far so good..**

This is what it does..

If nothing is selected... this message shows.

[image]

**Next.. database insertion.. (The actual complication)**

Above you'll see in the `else` statement I am calling `insertComplaintForm()` this is the function for it:

```
    private void insertComplaintForm()
    {

        var confirm = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure the details you have entered are Correct?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (confirm == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();

            db.InsertComplaint(best_before.Value);

            clearFields();

        }
    }
```

**DataAccess**

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public void InsertComplaint(DateTime _BestBeforeDate)
    {
        using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
        {
            List<ComplaintModel> complaint = new List<ComplaintModel>();

            complaint.Add(new ComplaintModel {BestBeforeDate = _BestBeforeDate});

            conn.Execute(@"INSERT INTO customer_complaints 
                        (best_before_date) 
                        VALUES (@BestBeforeDate)", complaint);
        }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

What would be the correct way to insert a `null` value if Combo Box was selected as `No` and insert the `BestBefore` Date if Combo Box was selected as `Yes`. I am not sure where is the correct way to add this code.

**My Intention**

My first intention is to do this..

Modify the function for `insertComplaintForm()` like so.

```
    private void insertComplaintForm()
    {

        string _best_before_date = ""; // New Line
        if(bestBeforeQuestion.SelectedItem == "Yes") // New Line
        {
            _best_before_date = best_before.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"); // New Line
        }
        if(bestBeforeQuestion.SelectedItem == "No") // New Line
        {
            _best_before_date = null; // New Line
        }

        var confirm = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure the details you have entered are Correct?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (confirm == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            DataAccess db = new DataAccess();

            db.InsertComplaint(DateTime.Parse(_best_before_date)); // Modified this line

            clearFields();

        }
    }
```

But I believe this should be validated in `ComplaintsValidator`.. keep everything where `Validation` is actually happening.. just not sure how to alter the values of the best before depending on the ComboBox selected value.